# Oracle 11.2 Configuring authentication

Tags: oracle

Can the following be setup in Oracle11.2 for password authentication?

1. A new, non temp password should be atleast 24 hours old before it can be changed. System admin and authorized help desk personnel may change passwords of any age.
2. Users will change temporary passwords including system administrator issued passwords at the first login.

I don't see these conditions in oracle documentation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at password profile in documentation.

Comment: It is not available in that documentation.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6010.htm

Comment: I don't see above mentioned conditions on the password profile.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the [security documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/authentication.htm#DBSEG30031) to answer your questions:

1. No, a minimum password life cannot be specified. Only a `PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME` (maximum life time) can be specified. Depending on what you want to accomplish, `PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME` might be what you're looking for. [(Source)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/authentication.htm#DBSEG0032)
2. Yes, this can be configured. You can expire a password, the user will then be prompted that he needs to change his password on first login. Look into the `PASSWORD EXPIRE` mechanism. [(Source)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/authentication.htm#i1007339)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the first part with a password verify function.
Query the name and ptime from `user$`, compare it to `sysdate` and when it hasn't been more than 24 hours raise an exception.
You can use the function from `utlpwdmg.sql` in the `ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin` directory or  alternative one
http://www.pentest.co.uk/sql/pentest_password_verify.pls
as a starting point. Then associate the verify function with a profile and the profile with the user(s).